# Why doesn't browser create correspond html code for opening audiofiles

Tags: html, google-chrome, specifications

If you try to open the audio file in a browser, the browser will create the following code:

```html
<video controls autoplay name="media">
     <source src="https://stopmusic.net/_ld/65/6549_B.B.E-Seven_Day.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</video>
```

Why does he create the markup using the `<video>` tag?

If we look at the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/browsers.html#page-load-processing-model-for-media), we will see the following:

> When an image, video, or audio resource is to be loaded in a browsing
>   context, the user agent should create a Document object, mark it as
>   being an HTML document, set its content type to the computed MIME type
>   of the resource (type in the navigate algorithm), initialize the
>   Document object, append an html element to the Document, append a head
>   element and a body element to the html element, append an element host
>   element for the media, as described below, to the body element, and
>   set the appropriate attribute of the element host element, as
>   described below, to the address of the image, video, or audio
>   resource.
>
> [image]

As you can see when opening a particular media file in a browser, the browser creates the specific code associated with it. And in this case, for some reason, the browser does not create the code associated with it. Why it happens? Is this an implementation specification error?

Comment: Safari and Firefox behave the same.

Comment: @JoshLee I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Maxthon. and I get same behaviour. Interesting why most (maybe all) browsers not corrrespond specification.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that this is something that Google Chrome does autonomously, I feel as though that they have their own proprietary algorithm that equates file types to specific tags such as `<video>`,`<audio>` and `<img>`. I would also think that a `.mp3` file would be opened by the `<audio>` tag and nothing else because it *is* an audio file. After considering these things, it makes no logical sense that this feature would perform the things that it does on the production side of things. One would assume that any file ending with the extension of 'mp4' to use the `<video>` tag. I think that this is a prime example of a feature that they were finishing up and decided to push it anyways because it ***worked*** and did not require any more effort.

Comment: This is your opinion, which doesn't make it a valid answer. Do you have referential proof of anything you assumed?

Comment: In particular, did you actually manage to produce an `<audio>` tag or are you just guessing?

Comment: I am looking further into this, Is it possible that he manually made it so it produced a `<video>` tag instead of an `<audio>` tag? Would this even be achievable?